# Problem with memory manament in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a method:

```
-(NSArray   *)doSomething{

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Huy 1",@"Huy 2",@"Huy 3",nil];

    [array  release];

    return  array;

}
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *array  =   [self   doSomething];

    if(array&&array.count>0){

        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",[array objectAtIndex:1]]);

    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"Null");

    }

}
```

I thinks i released array on doSomething() so it won't return NSArray which i created on doSomething(). I don't know it still print "Huy 2"? Anybody can tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(NSArray *)doSomething
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Huy 1",@"Huy 2",@"Huy 3",nil];

    return  [array autorelease];
}
```

[Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *array  =   [self doSomething];

    if([array count]) //if array is nil this will evaluate to false. If count is 0 this will evaluate to false too.
    {
        NSLog(@"%@\n", [array objectAtIndex:1]); //NSLog insert values for you
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Null");
    }
}
```

If this works with `release` instead of `autorelease` it's probably because the memory that the array was using has yet to be used by anything else. This is just chance. I suspect that if you allocate an object after `NSArray *array  =   [self doSomething];` you will get unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method in following way:

```
-(NSArray   *)doSomething{

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Huy 1",@"Huy 2",@"Huy 3",nil];

    return  [array autorelease];

}
```